# C++ Templates and Polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

I am working on a decision tree structure and since I will use similar decision structures with different agents, I decided to use templates to construct basic functionality.

Currently I have a class named `BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision` and it's inherited from template classes. The chain is `BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision -> DT_BoolDecision<T> -> DT_Decision<T> -> DT_Node<T>`

`DT_Node` class:

```
template <class entity_type>
class DT_Node
{
public:

    DT_Node() {}
    virtual ~DT_Node()
    {
        mNodes.clear();
    }

    virtual DT_Node* decide(entity_type* pAgentPtr) = 0;

    virtual void addChild(std::unique_ptr<DT_Node>&& pNewChild)
    {
        mNodes.emplace_back( std::move(pNewChild) );
    }

protected:

    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<DT_Node> > mNodes;
};
```

DT_Decision class:

```
template <class entity_type>
class DT_Decision : public DT_Node<entity_type>
{
public:

    DT_Decision()
        : DT_Node<entity_type>()
    {

    }

    virtual ~DT_Decision()
    {

    }

    DT_Node<entity_type>* decide(entity_type* pAgentPtr)
    {
        return getBranch(pAgentPtr)->decide(pAgentPtr);
    }

protected:

    virtual DT_Node<entity_type>* getBranch(entity_type* pAgentPtr) = 0;
};
```

`DT_BoolDecision` class:

```
template <class entity_type>
class DT_BoolDecision : public DT_Decision<entity_type>
{
public:

    enum eNODE_TYPE{ eNT_TRUE_NODE = 0, eNT_FALSE_NODE};

    DT_BoolDecision()
        : DT_Decision<entity_type>(),
          BRANCH_NUMBER(2)
    {

    }

    virtual ~DT_BoolDecision()
    {

    }

    void addChild(std::unique_ptr< DT_Node<entity_type> >&& pNewChild)
    {
        this->mNodes.emplace_back( std::move(pNewChild) );
    }

    void addChild(const eNODE_TYPE pNodeType, std::unique_ptr< DT_Node<entity_type> >&& pNewChild)
    {
        if(this->mNodes.size() <BRANCH_NUMBER)
        {
            this->mNodes.emplace( this->mNodes.begin() + (int)pNodeType, std::move(pNewChild) );
        }
    }

protected:

    virtual bool performTest(entity_type* pAgentPtr) = 0;

    DT_Node<entity_type>* getBranch(entity_type* pAgentPtr)
    {
        if( performTest(pAgentPtr) )
        {
            return this->mNodes[eNODE_TYPE::eNT_TRUE_NODE].get();
        }

        return this->mNodes[eNODE_TYPE::eNT_FALSE_NODE].get();
    }

    const int BRANCH_NUMBER;
};
```

`BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision` class:

```
// int for a simple test
class BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision : public DT_BoolDecision<int>
{
public:

    BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision();
    virtual ~BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision();

protected:

    bool performTest(int* pAgentPtr);
};
```

DT_Action (in case you need):

```
template <class entity_type>
class DT_Action : public DT_Node<entity_type>
{
public:

    DT_Action()
    : DT_Node<entity_type>()
    {}
    virtual ~DT_Action() {}

    DT_Node<entity_type>* decide(entity_type* pAgentPtr) { return this; }
    void addChild(std::unique_ptr< DT_Node<entity_type> >&& pNewChild) {}

    virtual void performAction(entity_type* pAgent) = 0;

};
```

And finally `DecisionTree` class:

```
template <class entity_type>
class DecisionTree
{
public:

    DecisionTree(entity_type* pAgentPtr)
    {
        mAgentPtr = pAgentPtr;
    }

    DecisionTree(entity_type* pAgentPtr, std::unique_ptr< DT_Node<entity_type> >&& pRoot)
    {
        mAgentPtr = pAgentPtr;
        mRoot = std::move(pRoot);
    }

    ~DecisionTree()
    {

    }

    void addRoot(std::unique_ptr< DT_Node<entity_type> >&& pRoot)
    {
        mRoot = std::move(pRoot);
    }

    void decide()
    {
        DT_Action<entity_type>* resultantAction = (DT_Action<entity_type>*)(mRoot->decide(mAgentPtr));
        if(resultantAction != nullptr)
        {
            resultantAction->performAction(mAgentPtr);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"ERROR! DT! FACED WITH A NULL DT_ACTION";
        }
    }

private:

    std::unique_ptr<DT_Node<entity_type>> mRoot;

    entity_type* mAgentPtr;
};
```

After I finished coding I decided to test it with a simple type (I chose `int`) and performed the following operations:

```
int test= 6;

std::unique_ptr<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision> testRoot = std::make_unique<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision>();
std::unique_ptr<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision> testNode = std::make_unique<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision>();

testRoot->addChild(testNode); // Error: No matching member function for call to 'addChild'
testRoot->addChild(DT_BoolDecision<int>::eNODE_TYPE::eNT_TRUE_NODE, testNode); // Error: No matching member function for call to 'addChild'

DecisionTree<int> dt(&test);
dt.addRoot(testRoot); // Error: No viable conversion from 'unique_ptr<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision>' to 'unique_ptr<DT_Node<int>>

dt.decide();
```

And received `No matching member function for call to 'addChild'` and `No viable conversion from 'unique_ptr<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision>' to 'unique_ptr<DT_Node<int>>` errors.

I could not come across any useful information related with my problem, so I have no insights to solve it.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to paste 3 pages of code here to find an error? Why you do not shrink it so that anyone can reproduce the problem?

Comment: This example is far from minimal; please spend some time yourself to narrow it down. Read what a [mcve] is.

Comment: and the class DT_Action is not present.. so nothing can compiled!

Comment: `testRoot->addChild(testNode);` `virtual void addChild(std::unique_ptr<DT_Node>&& pNewChild)` Would you like to [move it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)?

Comment: @Klaus Which parts I can cut, you tell me please? This is a chain of inheritance as I explained at the very beginning.

Comment: @Caninonos I am moving it in addChild(), that is why I did not consider to move it in the call.

Comment: @ciyo Well, that doesn't make it less necessary, if your function expects an [rvalue, don't give it an lvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). As an aside, if you add the `std::move`, your code will probably compile but I expect it to crash quickly. Do you know what happens when you move construct `unique_ptr` then try to access the original as if nothing happened? Here's a [hint](https://ideone.com/mspbzz)

Comment: @Caninonos it seems like the problem was moving it. I just added std::move() to the lines giving error and everything solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Caninonos I am not planning to access the original unique_ptrs after I moved their content. I will use them just for constructing the tree.

Comment: @ciyo My bad, I thought you called a method of `testRoot` after using it to move construct something (but I misread). Everything's fine then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error boils down to

```
struct Receiver
{
    void method(std::unique_ptr<int> ptr) {}
};

int main()
{
    Receiver receiver;
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>(10);
    receiver.method(ptr); // Error: No matching member function for call to 'method'
}
```

Which is because you are trying to *copy* `unique_ptr`s. You need to *move* them instead. And having done that, the moved-from `unique_ptr` will be empty.

```
std::unique_ptr<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision> testRoot = std::make_unique<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision>();
std::unique_ptr<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision> testNode = std::make_unique<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision>();

testRoot->addChild(std::move(testNode));

// You don't have a node in testNode anymore, so you need a new one to add again
testNode = std::make_unique<BC_IsEnemyCloseDecision>(); 

testRoot->addChild(DT_BoolDecision<int>::eNODE_TYPE::eNT_TRUE_NODE, std::move(testNode)); 

int test= 6;
DecisionTree<int> dt(&test);
dt.addRoot(std::move(testRoot)); 

dt.decide();
```